# Chose GameObject from SettingCollection

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, zenject

I'm using Zenject framework and I want instansiate gameObject for class created by factory. For this I'm using something like this in GameInstaller

```
Container.BindFactory<int,int,Hex, Hex.Factory().
    FromComponentInNewPrefab(_settings.PlainHexPrefab[0]).
    WithGameObjectName("Hex").
    UnderTransformGroup("Zenject");`
```

It's work fine, but in my case in _settings.PlainHexPrefab I have collection GameObjects and I need choose one of them dependency by properties from Hex object. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's three ways that might work for you:

1. FromMethod

   ```
   public class Hex : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public class Factory : PlaceholderFactory<int, int, Hex>
       {
       }
   }

   public class TestInstaller : MonoInstaller<TestInstaller>
   {
       public GameObject[] HexPrefabs;

       public override void InstallBindings()
       {
           Container.BindFactory<int, int, Hex, Hex.Factory>().FromMethod(CreateHex);
       }

       Hex CreateHex(DiContainer _, int p1, int p2)
       {
           var prefab = HexPrefabs[Random.RandomRange(0, HexPrefabs.Count() -1)];
           return Container.InstantiatePrefabForComponent<Hex>(prefab);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Custom Factory

   ```
   public class HexFactory : IFactory<int, int, Hex>
   {
       readonly DiContainer _container;
       readonly GameObject[] _prefabs;

       public HexFactory(
           GameObject[] prefabs,
           DiContainer container)
       {
           _container = container;
           _prefabs = prefabs;
       }

       public Hex Create(int p1, int p2)
       {
           var prefab = _prefabs[Random.RandomRange(0, _prefabs.Count() -1)];
           return _container.InstantiatePrefabForComponent<Hex>(prefab);
       }
   }

   public class TestInstaller : MonoInstaller<TestInstaller>
   {
       public GameObject[] HexPrefabs;

       public override void InstallBindings()
       {
           Container.BindFactory<int, int, Hex, Hex.Factory>()
               .FromIFactory(b => b.To<HexFactory>().AsSingle().WithArguments(HexPrefabs));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Sub factories in custom factory.  This also has the advantage that each prefab factory should be 'validated'

   ```
   public class CustomHexFactory : IFactory<int, Hex>
   {
       readonly List<Hex.Factory> _subFactories;

       public CustomHexFactory(List<Hex.Factory> subFactories)
       {
           _subFactories = subFactories;
       }

       public Hex Create(int p1)
       {
           return _subFactories[Random.RandomRange(0, _subFactories.Count() -1)].Create(p1);
       }
   }

   public class TestInstaller : MonoInstaller<TestInstaller>
   {
       public GameObject[] HexPrefabs;

       public override void InstallBindings()
       {
           foreach (var prefab in HexPrefabs)
           {
               Container.BindFactory<int, Hex, Hex.Factory>().FromComponentInNewPrefab(prefab)
                   .WhenInjectedInto<CustomHexFactory>();
           }

           Container.BindFactory<int, Hex, Hex.Factory>().FromFactory<CustomHexFactory>();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, I already did something like second variant with only two little defferences.
1) In installer i wrote `Container.BindFactory<int, int, float, float, Hex, Hex.Factory>().FromFactory<HexGameObjectFactory>();`

And it's the same as you suggestion as i understand
2) I pass prefab array directly in factory, but not in installer.

After that, I have two questions.
1) Is there a difference between these two approaches?
2) When project is building I got exception about resolve int type  in Hex object
 Unable to resolve type 'System.Int32' while building object with type 'Hex'.

Comment: Well, I found solve for problem with exception type 'Unable to resolve type 'System.Int32' while building object with type 'Hex''  
I just send parameters by factory:

   `public Hex Create(int param1, int param2, float param3, float param4)  
    {  
    //some code  
    var go = GetGOForHexType(el, moiT);  
    return _container.InstantiatePrefabForComponent<Hex>(go, new object[] { param1 , param2 , param3 , param4 });  
    }`

it's finally works, but I still think it's not perfect, may be you see more right way?

Comment: Yeah, using FromFactory is basically the same as what I did with FromIFactory (which you can see if you step into that method).   I did think of a third way that you could use and editted my answer to include it